# Permission denied (publickey) & Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Tags: git, github

I try to create new repository using command but the following error occurs, how can I resolve this?`my window is windows-7 pro

```
       PS C:\Users\Naing Min Zaw\Desktop\learningGit> git push -u origin main
       git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
       fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

      Please make sure you have the correct access rights
      and the repository exists.
```

I use this command in powershell

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin git@github.com:NaingMinZaw/learningGit.git
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: this is not java, nor javascript, html, css or angular, please remove all tags

Comment: please tag correctly your question to `git`, remove all other tags

Comment: thank Victor Polo De Gyves Montero

Comment: I think you need to setup SSH-keys. Refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGOj5yH7evk&t=1557s) youtube video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of

```
git -c "core.sshCommand='ssh -Tv'" push -u origin main
```

That will show you which SSH key is looked up by SSH during the push.

If you don't have an SSH key, [generate one](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) and add the public key to your [GitHub profile](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).